# The use of when reaction in MobX

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am trying to understand the use of when in MobX

I just created a simple store (the ErrorStore) that I want to use to save the application errors and when the observable changes notify and enpoint (or another component) to send the error details.
I'm using a an observable error which is a simple object and with a computed property intercept the change, everytime I set the error message and the activate flag to true then I reset it.
I don't know why the console message with the new error appears only once.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong.
Cheers

```
class ErrorStore {

    @observable error;

    constructor() {
        this.error = { 
            activate: false,
            message: ''
        }

        when (
            () => { this.errorGenerated; console.log("New error generated" , this.errorGenerated ) }  ,
            () => { 
                this.doRequest()
            }
        );

    }


    @computed get errorGenerated () {
        return (this.error.activate === true && this.error.message.length > 0);
    }

    @action setError = (message) => {
        this.error = Object.assign( this.error, { 
            activate : true,
            message : message
        })
    } 


    doRequest = async () => {
        let r = await axios.post({ 
            url : "/myendopoint",  
            data : { 
                error: this.error.message
            }
        });

        if(r.success) {
          console.log("Error has been sent")
                  this.reset()
        }
    }

   @action reset = () => {
        this.error = {
            activate: false,
            message: '',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add return in when first function (predicate)

```
when (
() => { console.log("New error generated" , this.errorGenerated ); 
        return this.errorGenerated;  
      },
() => { 
        this.doRequest()
      }
);
```

So what when does is when this.errorGenerated returns true it will call next  this.doRequest() (that will dispose this whole when)

For more reference check this example: https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/yXapdZ

For doc check this : https://mobx.js.org/refguide/when.html

Comment: Thank you @somsgod